# Two circles intersect at $C$, and their common tangents meet at $T$. Show $CT$ bisects the angle made by the two tangents at $C$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, homothety

> Two circles intersect at $C$ and $D$, and their common tangents intersect at $T$. $CP$ and $CQ$ are the tangents at $C$ to the two circles; prove that $CT$ bisects $\angle PCQ$.

I am aware of some basic theorems on the centres of similitude/homothety, but I'm not sure how to apply them to compute angles. Most of the other problems here have been about computing ratios of lengths.

Comment: You should add a diagram to explain clearly what you mean, as usual with geometry problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ be our circles, $\Gamma_1\cap\Gamma_2=\{C,D\}$,

$TM$ and $TK$ be common tangents to our circles, where $\{M,K\}\subset\Gamma_1.$

Also, let $P$ and $Q$ be placed on segments $MT$ and $KT$ respectively such that

$CP$ and $CQ$ are tangents to $\Gamma_2$ and $\Gamma_1$  respectively.

Now, let $TC\cap\Gamma_1=\{C,N\}$ and let $f$ be a homothety with the center $T$ such that $f(\Gamma_2)=\Gamma_1$.

Thus, $f(\{C\})=\{N\}$ and $f(CP)$ is a tangent to the circle $\Gamma_1$ in the point $N$,

which is parallel to $CP$ and let this tangent intersects $CQ$ in the point $R$.

Let $CP\cap \Gamma_1=\{L,C\}$.

Thus, since $NR||LP,$ we obtain $$\measuredangle PCT=\measuredangle NCL=\measuredangle RNC=\measuredangle RCN=\measuredangle QCT$$ and we are done!